# Formatting a string as the VisualStudio debugger does

Tags: visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

When I hover over a string that has binary data in it I see something like:

'abcdefg\0\0hijk\4lmnop'

When I view it in the TextVisualizer the binary data comes up as garbled text (particularly the '\0' character shows up as a small box) where the binary characters are located. This is the same "display" that I get if I were to put the string in a text display window. I would like to know how I can get the string that is formed by hovering over the string so that I can display the binary values.
Thank you.